# How to embed an ICC CMYK colour profile in Scribus

Tags: scribus

I need to embed an ICC CMYK colour profile in a PDF file using Scribus. 
I have done following documents setting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After saving, the PDF document, it does not have the ICC profile embedded, there are only out /OutputIntents in the PDF file.

Also, even I have installed the CMYK profile on my computer, it cannot show the CMYK ICC profile in the selection below *(PDF Export → color → use color profile).*

[image]

However, it does show the CMYK profile in *Pre-press → PDF/X Output Intent → Output Profile.*

Comment: I fear that your issue is similar to [How to embed CMYK color profile using Scribus in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291558) and you are only tweaking the PDF export settings and did not enable the color management...

Comment: Have you installed an ICC CMYK colour profile on your computer?  If not, go to the [ICC website](http://www.color.org), download one, and install it on your computer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you want to add more details, don't add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten after the questioner told that he has installed to Windows some CMYK color profiles and the question was written because those profiles seem not to be taken into use when making a PDF.

You should have in document setup Color Management=ON and you should define some profiles. You cannot see onscreen what you will get from CMYK printing, if you haven't defined CMYK printing color profile and set ON simulate printing. Gamut warning is useful too. It shows unprintable colors as bright green.

Start from this dialog:

[image]

Goto PDF print definition section and select in tab "General" PDF/X-3 file compatibility. It's the modern PDF version.

[image]

In Pre-press tab define the wanted CMYK print color profile:

[image]

You can redefine these just when you save as PDF. It's a good idea to have right color profiles in the beginning to avoid color conversions which are not lossless. Also design probably stays more easily coherent if you see right what you will get.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even I have installed icc colour profile and put into default windows path. but it is not showing cmyk icc colour profile in scribus (save as PDF--> Use colour Profile -- > profile)..it showing rgb profile only, any ideas about this issue.